# MySQL Prepared Statement - DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE using WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to update a column in a row when a duplicate key occurs. I only want to update the column if the column is not currently equal to "C". I have reviewed all the online information and this looks OK. However, the error message I get is that there is an error in the syntax near:

```
WHERE VALUES(cad_status_flag) <> 'C' OR VALES(cad_status_flag) IS NULL
```

I have tried without VALUES, i.e., WHERE cad_status_flag <> 'C' OR ad_status_flag IS NULL with the same error message occurring.

The SQL is:

```
String selectQry5 = ("INSERT INTO at_cub_award_date " +
            "(ca_id, ad_id, cad_task_completion_date, cad_status_flag) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) " +
            //"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cad_status_flag=? WHERE VALUES(cad_status_flag) <> 'C' OR VALUES(cad_status_flag) IS NULL;");
```

**MySQL does not allow WHERE so I replaced it with IF**

```
"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +
    "cad_status_flag = IF(cad_status_flag <> 'C' OR cad_status_flag IS NULL, VALUES(cad_status_flag), cad_status_flag;");
//Create the at_cub_award_date order 1 row
        try {
            // Create a statement and execute the query on it               
            ps5.setString(1, caid);
            ps5.setString(2, adid);
            ps5.setString(3, awardedDate);
            ps5.setString(4, groupCompleted);
            ps5.setString(5, groupCompleted);

            ps5.executeUpdate();

            //Get foreign key from insert into at_cub_awards
            ResultSet rs = ps5.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (rs.next()) {
                ymAwards = new YMAwards(rs.getString(1), null, null, null, null);
            };

            // Clean up
            ps5.close();
            c.close();
            System.out.println("addYMAwards5 completed: ");

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("SQLException in addYMAwards5: " + se.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Errors occurred in addYMAwards5: " + e.toString());
        }
```

Now I get the error "SQLException in addYMAwards5: com.mysql.jdbc.exception.jdbc.exzception.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to yor MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Do you really have a function `VALES()` (you use it in your WHERE clause (`VALES(cad_status_flag) IS NULL`) - it looks like a typo and that you meant to use `VALUES()` again).

Comment: Can you provide the error as well?

Comment: I have found that MySQL does not allow WHERE clause. You have to use IF. I have amended above.

Comment: My update was missing a right bracket. Please see below for the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to follow your logic.  You seem to want a `CASE` statement in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO at_cub_award_date(ca_id, ad_id, cad_task_completion_date, cad_status_flag) 
    SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?
    FROM dual
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        cad_status_flag = (CASE WHEN VALUES(cad_status_flag) <> 'C' OR VALUES(cad_status_flag) IS NULL
                                THEN ? ELSE cad_status_flag
                           END);
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not allow WHERE, you have to use IF.

```
String selectQry5 = ("INSERT INTO at_cub_award_date " +
            "(ca_id, ad_id, cad_task_completion_date, cad_status_flag) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) " +
            "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +
                "cad_status_flag = IF(cad_status_flag <> 'C' OR cad_status_flag IS NULL, VALUES(cad_status_flag), cad_status_flag);");
```

Note: VALUES(cad_status_flag) can be replaced by ? as long as you add ps5.setString(5, groupCompleted); in the prepared statement.